# Load signed extension in the DUCKDB ODBC connection

Tags: odbc, duckdb

I'm trying to find where/how to load a signed extension, the spatial one specifically, in the duckdb ODBC connection. I can't seem to find any documentation on how this is done.

Is this possible?

Here is what the ODBC.ini looks like

```
[ODBC 32 bit Data Sources]
DuckDB=DuckDB Driver (32 bit)
[DuckDB]
Driver32=C:\TEMP\duckdb_odbc-windows-amd64\duckdb_odbc.dll
```

Comment: Hi Messak, this is currently not supported but will appear in the nightly build sometime soon. I'll post an answer when that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODBC driver now supports loading extensions, including unsigned extensions, see https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/pull/10692

See also the documentation: https://duckdb.org/docs/api/odbc/macos#the-odbcini-or-odbcini-file